# why does ssh to localhost as another user on windows 10 still asks for password even after key-pair is set up?

Tags: windows-10, ssh, localhost, ssh-keys

- I am using Windows 10 as Username: poh
- I want to ssh into localhost as another User: ml
- I have done the following steps in Powershell:

  - ssh-keygen -t rsa
  - ssh ml@localhost mkdir -p .ssh
  - cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh ml@localhost  'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
  - ssh ml@localhost  "chmod 700 .ssh"
  - ssh ml@localhost  "chmod 640 .ssh/authorized_keys"
  - ssh ml@localhost
- I am not completely sure if the chmod commands are applied. I don't get any error
- I am referencing this tutorial here : https://www.tecmint.com/ssh-passwordless-login-using-ssh-keygen-in-5-easy-steps/

Here is the log:

```
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\poh/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\poh/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\poh/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\poh/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\poh/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\poh/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\poh/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\poh/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\poh/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\poh/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7
debug1: match: OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to localhost:22 as 'ml'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:HeukCvI+5/16l0qk++uc8EEeQZ5WSxtY1/J4JfA/dus
debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\poh/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:HStAW/roMiGspuGBMFDCtzQvhWnC0xqDcMF5Ur6Ze+I C:\\Users\\poh/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\poh/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\poh/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\poh/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\poh/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
```

I really appreciate the help. Thank you !

Comment: You created an RSA key but RSA is never tried on login. Hence I would assume OpenSSH is configured to not use RSA. Beter create an DSA or ECDSA key (or better first check if there is not already ansuch a key in `C:\Users\poh/.ssh/`.

Comment: Tried creating both dsa and ecdsa keys. Still no luck...

Comment: Check out this how-to for sshd on Windows: https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_keymanagement The command near then titled as "Appropriately ACL the authorized_keys file on your server" looks interesting.

Comment: Thank you. It did not exactly solve the issue since some things are deprecated in the newer builds. However, it did find something that worked. in this stackoverflow entry. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16212816/setting-up-openssh-for-windows-using-public-key-authentication/50502015#50502015
I did the exact steps in the reply by 'nord'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a soultion in this stackoverflow entry:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16212816/setting-up-openssh-for-windows-using-public-key-authentication/50502015#50502015
I did the exact steps in the reply by 'n0rd'